# update custom configuration file in Docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, jboss, wildfly

I am new to **Docker**. My requirement is to create a docker file which should install `Wildfly` server, add war file to `Wildfly`, add custom property file (which contains db connection strings which will read by application)

**My Docker file**

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
Add application.properties /opt/jboss/
ADD spring_application.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

**application.properties**

```
db_url = jdbc:mysql://**server host name**:**port**
db_username = **username**
db_password = **password**
```

Note: in the above file server host name, port, username, password should be dynamic

**War** file (spring rest application) will read parameters from application.properties

I am able successfully install `Wildfly` and deployed application. Now i need to pass parameters in application.properties at runtime. Please help me if anyone has solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by overwriting entrypoint script. Here is example run.sh script which creates application.properties file before booting application.

**run.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -x
PROPERTIES=/opt/jboss/application.properties
echo "db_url = jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST}:${MYSQL_PORT}" > ${PROPERTIES}
echo "db_username = ${MYSQL_USER}" >> ${PROPERTIES}
echo "db_password = ${MYSQL_PASS}" >> ${PROPERTIES}
exec /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 $@
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
ADD run.sh /run.sh
CMD /run.sh
ADD spring_application.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

Run this with:

```
docker run -e MYSQL_HOST=mysqlhost -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_PASS=pass wildflyimage
```